# Как соединить веб-хук Discord с ботом?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пытаюсь написать бота, который бы проигрывал музыку, транслирующуюся с помощью azuracast и оповещающий о новых треках.

На моём тестовом сервере есть два бота: один из них проигрывает музыку, другой является веб-хуком, который и занимается оповещениями. Задачей является встраивание функций второго в первый. Пока что непонятно как это сделать, так как azuracast передаёт информацию по URL веб-хука; а каким образом эту информацию получить боту — неясно.

Есть ли какое-то решение данной проблемы?